# C# Crop Image based on unifrom color?

Tags: c#, image-processing

Is there a way to crops image by removing borders of uniform color ?

EDIT: Based on the similar topic, I tried to use AForge.NET package - Extract biggest blob, it dint work.

[image: 2]

I have tried using all the Blob extract functions and All I get is just the channel extract, I need to perform this after I do the Green channel extract. I even tried the extract Black just in case. That too dint work.

Here is my code that I have tried.

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)// File-Open - Import image and show in PictureBox1
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.Title = "Open Image";
            dlg.Filter = "bmp files (*.bmp)|*.bmp";
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                ClearCurrentImage();

                pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(dlg.FileName);
                ////------ AForge.NET sequence------//
                //// create filter
                //SaturationCorrection filter = new SaturationCorrection(-0.5f);
                //// apply the filter
                //filter.ApplyInPlace(image);
                ////------ AForge.NET sequence------//

                // Pass original image to the channel extract filter
                Bitmap image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
                //Create filters
                ExtractChannel GreenChannel = new ExtractChannel(RGB.G);
                //ExtractBiggestBlob BlobGreenChannel = new ExtractBiggestBlob();
                //RotateBilinear RotateFilter = new RotateBilinear(30, true);
                Shrink Blackfilter = new Shrink(Color.Black);
                // ---------------- Apply filter ------------------//
                Bitmap ChannelImage = GreenChannel.Apply(image);
                //Bitmap BlobChannelImage = BlobGreenChannel.Apply(image);
                //Bitmap RBCImage = RotateFilter.Apply(BlobGreenChannel.Apply(GreenChannel.Apply(image)));
                //Bitmap BlobChannelImage = BlobGreenChannel.Apply(GreenChannel.Apply(image));
                //Bitmap BRBCImage = Blackfilter.Apply(RotateFilter.Apply(BlobGreenChannel.Apply(GreenChannel.Apply(image))));
                Bitmap BlackImage = Blackfilter.Apply(GreenChannel.Apply(image));
                pictureBox2.Image = BlackImage;
            }
            dlg.Dispose();
        }
```

I would like to fit the image in the smallest rectangle possible by cropping away all the black background. How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the rectangle area of image to Crop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593864/find-the-rectangle-area-of-image-to-crop)

Comment: find bounding box (process all pixels and remember min and max x,y coordinates of non background color pixels) that is the cropped area `(minx,miny,maxx,maxy)`

Comment: Could you please explain about the bounding box, I tried to use the blob extract from AForge, wasn't successful.

Comment: Another idea is to use edge detect and crop that area from original, but I am not sure how I can do that.